# Update a existing deployed farm solution

Tags: 2010, development, solution-package, solution-deployment, farm-solution

I've deployed a farm solution to a test environment by following the Technet [Deploy solution packages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995%28office.14%29.aspx#DeployFarmSolutions) page - works well. But development continues, and I need to redeploy.

When I follow the process again I get the error

> Add-SPSolution: A solution with the same name "awesomewebparts.wsp" or id "[a random identifier string]" already exists in the solution store.

I gather that I need to either remove the existing version before adding the new version, or issuing a different command to update or overwrite the existing version. Can anyone provide any direction on how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to retract and then remove the solution through Central Administration, which allows it to be redeployed.

- In Central Adminstration, select System Settings.
- From the Farm Management section, select 'Manage farm solutions'.
- Select the solution you want to remove.
- Click 'Retract Solution' and confirm. The solution will retract (undeploy)
- Click 'Remove Solution' and confirm. The solution will be removed and can be be re-added.

I'm interested to know if there is any other way to redeploy a solution without uninstalling.

Comment: I'm going with the answer because I need to provide advice to our SharePoint administrators on how to deploy and update, and this is the most 'user friendly' (i.e. simplest) method.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Update-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

Use powershell commands:

```
Uninstall-SPSolution
Remove-SPSolution
```

Uninstall-SPSolution uses some sort of timer job to actually, so it can take 15-45 seconds for the Uninstall to finish.

This guy has a reasonable complicated script for automating this:
    http://jmkristiansen.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/automatically-retract-remove-add-and-deploy-sharepoint-2010-wsp-solution-files-with-powershell/